# Make itemize label vertical text

Tags: itemize

I am attempting to make a nice itemize labels for my argument.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[$A$] Something.
\item[$A\rightarrow B$] Something.
\item[$B$] Conclusion.
\end{itemize}
```

So far, so good. This code generates a nice list. However, the A → B aligns so that its final letter B aligns with the A and B for the other items, whilst the 'A →' sticks out to the left, like in the following image:

[image: My list]

I was wondering whether I could make the 'A → B' label vertical, to have something like this instead:

A

↓

B

I have tried to search the internet for this, but I have found nothing so far. Perhaps I am using the wrong keywords.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Is use of the `\item[$\downarrow$] Something`  instead of `\item[$A\rightarrow B$] Something.` what you after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ABc{% center aligned
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    A\\[-0.5ex]
    \downarrow\\[-0.3ex]
    B
  \end{array}%
}
\newcommand\ABt{% top aligned
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    A\\[-0.5ex]
    \downarrow\\[-0.3ex]
    B
  \end{array}%
}
\newcommand\ABb{% bottom aligned
  \begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    A\\[-0.5ex]
    \downarrow\\[-0.3ex]
    B
  \end{array}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$A$] Something.
\item[$\ABc$] Something, center aligned.
\item[$\ABt$] Something, top aligned.
\item[$\ABb$] Something, bottom aligned.
\item[$B$] Conclusion.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may have to `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `{\smash[b]{<v-array>}}` if the `\item` text is longer than a single line.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for the advice. At the moment I'm waiting for the OP to indicate which alternative he prefers. Then I will probably need some smash. But feel free to copy my answer and improve it. Zero problem to delete my answer if a better one comes along ;-)